# Is there a way to fix "connection limited" problems on Windows without restart?

Tags: networking, windows-8

Occasionally on my Windows 8.1 the ethernet connection goes to "connection limited" state and the net stops working.

However, the router is still connected to the net, because the connection still works when switching to WiFi.

Restarting the router does not help with the issue, only rebooting Windows fixes it, so apparently something goes wrong in the ethernet networking stack which causes it to stuck in "limited" state which reboot fixes.

Is there a way to fix this without rebooting the computer?

Comment: Have you tried to disable and enable the network adapter that is failing? You might consider troubleshooting the reason the connection goes to the state, instead of restarting the device or adapter, to address the symptoms of the actual problem.

Comment: @Ramhound   I read a tip about disabling/enabling the network adapter, so I tried that too, but the connection stayed in limited state regardless until I rebooted the computer

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/688049/windows-shows-limited-connection-when-it-isnt?rq=1) suggests, disabling EnableActiveProbing, is also a necessary step.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it next time when the problem occurs and report back with the results.